# Spring Tool Suite marca error en carpeta src/main/ donde esta la carpeta de vistas que no se pueden mapear

Tags: java, mvc, spring-boot, spring, spring-tool-suite

Estoy creando un proyecto Spring MVC, mapeo un metodo en el controller que retorne a la vista mensajes.jsp pero no logra cargarla, la carpeta src/main marca un error pero no sé cual es, en el navegador me da el sgte error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    mensajes cannot be resolved to a variable
```

el archivo application.properties lo tengo configurado así:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

STS no me da ninguna información sobre el error en dicha carpeta
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI3nB.png

Comment: Tienes un errores en todos tus métodos en la foto que adjuntas. Estás devolviendo una variable `mensajes` que no veo que exista en ningún lado. Si pretendes devolver la vista debes devolver un string : `return "mensajes"`. Ese string es el nombre de la vista.

Comment: Toda la razón, lo corregí pero aun sigue sin cargar la vista, la consola me tira un warn: ```Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/views/mensajes.jsp]```

Comment: Intenta [esta solución](https://www.yawintutor.com/warn-3200-path-with-web-inf-or-meta-inf/#:~:text=The%20spring%20boot%20error%20Path,tomcat%20embedded%20jasper%20maven%20dependency.) agregando `tomcat jasper` al `pom`. Recuerda `reload` el `pom` después de agregar la dependencia.

Comment: agregué esa dependencia aunque no tengo claro si resolvió el problema, le estaba enviando una lista a la vista la cual no recibía, luego la recibí con jstl pero no tenia la dependencia tampoco, se la agregué y por fin funcionó, gracias!

Comment: Para trabajar con jsp en springboot necesitas necesariamente esa dependencia. Como springboot se ejecuta en un tomcat integrado y no en un server externo, necesita jasper para poder compilar jsp. Me alegra te haya funcionado.